# Length of salt in CRYPT_BLOWFISH

Tags: php, bcrypt

In PHP manual states that:

> CRYPT_BLOWFISH - Blowfish hashing with a salt as follows: "$2a$", a
>   two digit cost parameter, "$", and 22 digits from the alphabet
>   "./0-9A-Za-z".

I realized that the *Length of salt is 22*. I wrote following code and noticed in the output length of *salt* is *21*.

```
$encoded = crypt('pass','$2a$08$QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMK'); // Lenght of Q . . . K is 22
echo $encoded;
```

Output:

> $2a$08$QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJM./CR85.t4YytTnmLXsRJMfbYWopbT8Nu

*K* doesn't exist in the *salt*: **QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJM**

There is something I don't understand?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Why does K have to be in the salt?

Comment: Because `K` is in the `salt` string, it's not enough ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to how the salt is encoded. The actual salt is 128 bit but the encoded salt in the `crypt` format is 22 character · 8 bit/character · 3/4 = 132 bit. So 4 bits of the encoded salt are not actually used.

This also means that there are 16 encoded salts that result in the same hash as the first four bits of their least significant character are identical:

```
$hashes = array();
$chars = array_merge(array('.','/'), range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range('0','9'));
foreach ($chars as $char) {
    $salt = 'QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJM'.$char;
    $hashes[$salt] = crypt('pass','$2a$08$'.$salt);
}
var_dump($hashes);
```

Here are the encoded salts that result in the same hash:

```
QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJM.
QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJM/
QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMA
QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMB
QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMC
QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMD
QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJME
QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMF
QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMG
QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMH
QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMI
QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMJ
QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMK
QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJML
QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMM
QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMN
```

`crypt` probably simply uses the first that encodes the internally used 128 bit salt, which is `QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJM.`.

Comment: Don't understand this: `3/4 = 132 bit. ` what dose it mean?

Comment: @msoa [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encodes three bytes of input with four bytes of encoded output. And in the reverse process, four bytes of encoded input are decoded to three bytes of output. That’s why 22 bytes of Base64-encoded data results in 132 bits decoded data.

Comment: **More easily:** Each Based64 encoded character takes 6-bit. `22*6 = 132`

Comment: **A question remains:** In Base64 index table there is no `.` character, do `crypt` internally convert `+` or `/` or any characters to `.`? Or when Base64-decoding this happens?

Comment: @msoa bcrypt does not use the [standard Base64 alphabet](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#section-4) but a slightly different one: its order is `.`, `/`, `A`…`Z`, `a`…`z`, `0`…`9` in opposite to `A`…`Z`, `a`…`z`, `0`…`9`, `+`, `/`.