# What is the format of password_hash output?

Tags: php, passwords, verify, php-password-hash

I know the PHP function, `password_hash` outputs the algorithm, cost, salt, and hash all in one string so `password_verify` can check a password.

Sample output from [PHP page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php):

```
$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a
```

so the *$2y$* represents the algorithm, the *10* represents cost. 
But how does `password_verify` separate the salt from the hash? I don't see any identifier separating the two afterwards.

Comment: It doesn't need a separator because the algorithm guarantees the length of the hash.

Comment: The salt is packed into the first X bits of the hash according to the specified algorithm.

Comment: Gotcha, found more info about CRYPT_BLOWFISH in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15727563/761902. The salt is the first 21 characters of the hash.

Comment: It would be nice knowing the "format" (econding) of the output, because If I assume UTF8, it doesn't work right when you do the same hash both in php and javascript but is not documented anywhere wich one is the correct encoding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Length of salt in CRYPT\_BLOWFISH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727257/length-of-salt-in-crypt-blowfish)

Comment: @DarioOO Character sets don't play a role in this - the salt is encoded with a bcrypt-specific version of Base64, which only uses ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2):

For the bCrypt version of Password Hash.
Bcrypt has a fixed-length salt value. The crypt function which is what PHP calls internally when you're utilizing password_hash()/password_verify() with the default algorithm has a a 16 byte salt. This is given as a 22 characters of the custom base64 alphabet `A-Za-z/.` then it decodes the string into bytes as 22 B64 characters encode 16.5Bytes there is an extra nibble of data that is not taken into account.

For all other hashes the salt value is a defined set of bytes which are of course encoded into ASCII safe b64 and put after the `$` sign and then the verifying function would only have to split the string into parts via the delimiter `$` and then go for the third set of characters get the `substr(0,B64_ENCODED_HASH_ALGORITHM_SALT_LEN)`. After that it would then pass the parameters it also got from the split string and pass those back into the `password_hash` function along with the password to check.

The string it gives you is defined by the hashing algorithm's standard in most cases but is almost always something to the pattern of

`$<ALGORITHM_ID>$<COST_IN_FORMAT>$<BASE64_ENCODED_SALT><BASE64_ENCODED_HASH>$`