# Why string hashed with its hash as salt returns the hash?

Tags: php, security, hash, passwords

I was reading up on password security in PHP and I stumbled upon an interesting statement:

> Hashing the password with its hash as the salt returns the same hash

Without much thinking, I went on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) and found that is says the same thing.

Let's look at an example:

```
crypt("test", "test"); -> teH0wLIpW0gyQ
crypt("test", "teH0wLIpW0gyQ"); -> teH0wLIpW0gyQ
```

I can totally understand that crypt in PHP generates a one-way hash of the given string.

1. What I don't understand is how can we obtain the same hash output using two completely different salts?
2. Does it mean there are possibly other salts that could possibly give me the same hash?

**Follow up**

Thank you all for your pointers. I can see now that the default behavior is to use only the first two characters of the salt, which totally answers all my questions. Feels like a silly thing, but...

Comment: The answer to #2 is trivially yes, due to the pigeonhole principle. This affects virtually everything built on hashes and is not a problem in a well-engineered system, as *none* of the inputs generating the same hash are feasible to guess or find out.

Comment: The answer to #1 is: it depends on the cryptographic algorithm. There it no universal answer to that question. I do not know the underlying workings of the `crypt` function, but even if I did, I doubt it'd be a short answer ;-)

Comment: Generally, yes; there can be more than one salt which will give the same hash, but with a well-oiled website, this shouldn't be a major cause for concern

Comment: Read the manual, it’s all there: “Standard DES-based hash with a two character salt from the alphabet "./0-9A-Za-z".”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1‍. What I don't understand is how can we obtain the same hash output using two completely different salts?

Although you provided different salts to the `crypt` function, it uses the same salt internally, i. e., `te`. This is due to how `crypt` is implemented:

> Standard DES-based hash with a two character salt from the alphabet "./0-9A-Za-z".

So even if you provide a salt longer than 2 characters it will only take the first two.

And as `crypt`’s output contains the used salt prepended to the calculated hash, using a `crypt` hash as salt results in exactly the same output. And that’s just perfect as then the following can be used to verify a stored password:

```
crypt($password, $hash) === $hash
```

> 2‍. Does it mean there are possibly other salts that could possibly give me the same hash?

Yes. [This does also apply to other `crypt` algorithms like *bcrypt*.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15727563/53114)

Answer (score 5):

This is done on purpose. Your crypt function, when second argument consists of letters and digits, uses only two first characters of "salt" for encrypting, and those two characters are placed at the beginning of the result.
So,

```
crypt("test", "test");        -> teH0wLIpW0gyQ
crypt("test", "te");          -> teH0wLIpW0gyQ
crypt("test", "tea");         -> teH0wLIpW0gyQ
crypt("test", "temperature"); -> teH0wLIpW0gyQ
etc.
```

This is done for easy password correctness checking, so that
`crypt($password, crypt($password, $salt)) == crypt($password, $salt)`